# Laravel, get the returned value from call method

Tags: php, laravel, shell, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm writting some custom commands for laravel and I need to get the returned value from one command called from the other, for example:

```
class One extends Illuminate\Console\Command
{
  protected $signature = 'cmd:one';

  public function handle()
  {
    // call 'Two' and uses the api information to continue
    $returnedValue = $this->call('cmd:two');

    dd($returnedValue) // int(1) ?? it seems to show exit code
  }
}



class Two extends Illuminate\Console\Command
{
  protected $signature = 'cmd:two';

  public function handle()
  {
    // this command retrieves some api information needed to continue
    return $infoFromAPI;
  }
}
```

I also tried calling statically Artisan::call(...) with the same result.

I know there is an $output property but doc is not clear about how use it.

Comment: What do you mean by returned value? `// int(1) ?? it seems to show exit code` Thats because console commands return the exit code.

Comment: instead the exit code I'd like to get some data from that command, an array in this case.

Comment: I got a solution `$cmd = new Two; $returnedInfo = $cmd->handle(); dd($returnedValue); // it's ok` but that is not so clean as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information returned from `handle` finally goes to this line:

```
return is_numeric($statusCode) ? (int) $statusCode : 0;
```

so if in command `Two` you return `2` then result `$returnedValue` will be 2 but if you return array or 'test' string it will be 0.

So In fact you cannot do it like this. Result of command has to be numeric, so you cannot return for example array and reuse it in another command. In fact I don't think there is much point to run another command. You should rather create service that will call the endpoint and return result and if you need those 2 command, then you can call this service in 2 command and get result or if you cannot do it, you should put result from some storage (database/cache) and then use result from this storage in command `One`

Comment: Thank you, in `$this->output();` $this is instance of Command? because it exits with Method output does not exist.

Comment: Yes, doing a service a clean solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can return just about anything you like from a command if you ignore all best practices. for instance instead of

```
return $myarray;
```

which gets filtered through the is_numeric filter you can just

```
print_r($myJsonArray);
```

and in your other command

```
ob_start();
```

//call other command

```
$return = ob_get_clean();
```

and that is how to do everything badly but,  it will work.

Comment: hehe like the dirty old times.